# Og Membership entity not created when assigning new node to Group; works when editing node

Tags: 7, organic-groups

Using Organic Groups 7.x-2.9, I have two content types:
- Series (Group)
- Event (Group Content)

When creating an Event, a users has a select list of the Series they can assign this Event to (`og_group_ref`).  However, upon saving this new Event there is no `og_membership` entity created (recorded in the table `og_membership`) and, therefore, the new Event is not in the Series group.

If you then edit this event and select the Series, the `og_membership` entity is created and the relationship is reflected on the Event. (Possibly related, there is *no* data in the table `field_data_og_group_ref`).

Using breakpoints - everything appears to be the same with one exception: When `OgMembership::save()` is called during the creation of a new entity the event entity object *does* have the nid; however, the node (Event) has not yet been saved in the `node` table.

What needs to be done in order to have the relationship when a new node (that is a group content) is created?

[EDIT] It *seems* the `og_membership` entity is being saved and then deleted.  I found this [issue regarding data loss](https://www.drupal.org/project/og/issues/2148047).  I don't think it's related (as of yet) because I don't have any active OG rules; however, it did make me check further.  When creating group content and associating it with a group, the `og_membership` table auto increment **does** increase by 1, although no record was written.  This tells me a record was written and deleted.

[EDIT] The above linked issue led me to another `hook_node_insert` that is used in this site.  This hook uses `entity_metadata_wrapper` to set a field value, commenting this out stops the og_membership entity from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be a `hook_node_insert` using `entity_metadata_wrapper`.  I refactored that code to use `hook_node_presave` to set the field value (field unrelated to organic group) instead: `$node->field_short_url_code[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $string;` and all is well.